# Find the result of an indefinite integral: $\displaystyle\int\cos(x)\sin(nx)\,\Bbb dx$

Tags: integration

For $f(x)=\cos(x)$, where $0<x<\pi$, expanded into Fourier’s sine series, we will encounter an integral like $$\int\cos(x)\sin(nx)\,\Bbb dx.$$ But my basic skills are not very solid, and it is still difficult to find $$\int\cos(x)\sin(nx)\,\Bbb dx.$$

Comment: double integration by part should work...

Comment: If you are only interested in the result WolframAlpha does the job.

Comment: Look up the tableau method for integration by parts. It makes the whole thing much more straightforward to process.

Comment: You can use Mathematica to verify your calculation `Integrate[Cos[x]*Sin[n*x], x] // FullSimplify`  $\frac{\sin (x) \sin (n x)+n \cos (x) \cos (n x)}{1-n^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be calculated as follows:
$$\begin{align*}I_n:&=\int\cos(x)\sin(nx)dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\cos(x)\sin(nx)+\cos(x)\sin(nx)\right]dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\cos(x)\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)\sin(x)+\cos(x)\sin(nx)-\cos(nx)\sin(x)\right]dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\sin((n+1)x)+\sin((n-1)x)\right]dx\end{align*}$$
At this point you have to distinguish some cases. For $n=1$ the integral $I_1$ becomes:
$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(2x)dx=-\frac{\cos(2x)}{4}+C=-\frac{1-2\sin^2(x)}{4}+C=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}+C'$$ While:
$$I_{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(-2x)dx=-I_1=-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}-C'=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{2}+C''$$
In generale, for $n\neq\pm 1$, the result is:
$$I_{n\neq\pm 1}=-\frac{\cos((n+1)x)}{2(n+1)}-\frac{\cos((n-1)x)}{2(n-1)}+\tilde C$$